# Reading from multipart/form-data POST

Tags: c#, post

I am trying to read the PDF file using C#. The message will come in the form of a multipart/form-data POST. Example is as below but no matter what i try, I can not read the bytes.

I am reading the keys;

```
               string[] keys = Request.Form.AllKeys;
                for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
                {
                    w.WriteLine(keys[i] + ": " + Request.Form[keys[i]] + "<br>");
                }
```

output;

```
transactionId: 6350<br>
orderId: 314053<br>
orderStatus: Ready<br>
customerReferenceId: 7<br>
filename: Bk-314053-tx6350-Mess.pdf<br>
fileformat: pdf<br>
```

But having hard time to load pdf binary data..

```
    ------------d0f32ac86c8249c9aa562c1fcfbfeb66
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="transactionId"

17
------------d0f32ac86c8249c9aa562c1fcfbfeb66
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="orderId"

40274
------------d0f32ac86c8249c9aa562c1fcfbfeb66
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="orderStatus"

Ready
------------d0f32ac86c8249c9aa562c1fcfbfeb66
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="paymentId"

3
------------d0f32ac86c8249c9aa562c1fcfbfeb66
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="paymentAmount"

34.95
------------d0f32ac86c8249c9aa562c1fcfbfeb66
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="customerReferenceId"

7
------------d0f32ac86c8249c9aa562c1fcfbfeb66
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="referenceId"

11223344
------------d0f32ac86c8249c9aa562c1fcfbfeb66
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="referenceText"

I am reference text
------------d0f32ac86c8249c9aa562c1fcfbfeb66
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"

Bk-40274-tx17-Mess.pdf
------------d0f32ac86c8249c9aa562c1fcfbfeb66
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileformat"

pdf
------------d0f32ac86c8249c9aa562c1fcfbfeb66
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Bk-40274-tx17-Mess.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

<BINARY PDF BYTES DATA>
```

Comment: _"The message will come in the form of a multipart/form-data POST"_ - can you demonstrate by what mechanism you are receiving this POST, and add the relevant tags to your question?

Comment: We submit a form with a "Postback Url" , later on their API posts the multipart/Form-data to this postback url.. That's all the information that is provided from their documentation.

Comment: Have you tried saving the bytes into a file and view it via a PDF reader? Maybe its an image or something similar?

Comment: I reiterate my question: how are you currently **receiving** this? Show us the non-working code. I'm guessing that you're probably using ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core, but it's not clear from your question (and ASP.NET vs ASP.NET Core might be a tiny bit different in terms of the solution).

Comment: I have done this 
var parser = new MultipartFormDataParser(Request.InputStream);
var fileData = parser.GetParameterValue("file");

I am not sure if Request.InputStream is correct though... 

And I am using asp.net